# Accidentally Interrupted cProfile

Tags: python, recovery, keyboardinterrupt

After a long function call (16 hours), I ended it early with KeyboardInterrupt, but accidentally also interrupted cProfile, because it was taking so long to respond. In the Debug Stackviewer, I am faced with this:

- KeyboardInterrupt:

  - idlelib.run.runcode (...)
  - __ main __.< module > (...)
  - cProfile.run (...)
  - profile.run (...)
  - profile._show (...)
  - cProfile.print_stats (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap.find_spec (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap._get_spec (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap.find_spec (...)
  - importlib._bootstrap._path_stat (...)

Is there any way to recover what cProfile would have printed, and is there a way to more smartly use cProfile for excessively long function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all captured information was lost when the process exited. You might consider using the [`profiling`](https://github.com/what-studio/profiling) package that provides profile output while your program runs. I have been intending to use it with some of my interactive programs.